# Printer Printing Cutting Off Strings

Tags: c#, printing

I'm using this code to print a collection of strings from a Rich Text Box:

```
private void printBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
        p.OriginAtMargins = true;
        Margins pMargins = new Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
        p.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = pMargins;

        p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
        {
            e1.Graphics.DrawString(summaryBox.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
        };
        try
        {
            p.Print();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error During Printing", ex);
        }
    }
```

However, long strings get cut off and don't automatically. Strings cut off to the right, and after the first page is filled, a second page is not printed and leftover content is simply ignored. Are the problems with the printer setup or with the rich text box or both? How can I make sure long strings wrap and second or third pages are printed if the content is too long?

Comment: I added my answer below. if it help then plz mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and vote up by clicking up arrow to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [PrintPageEventArgs.MarginBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.marginbounds?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get printable area within a print page.

Now your `e1` is the parameter of type `PrintPageEventArgs`. and you will get `MarginBounds` like `e1.MarginBounds`.

So your code will be.

```
p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
{
    e1.Graphics.DrawString(summaryBox.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, e1.MarginBounds.Width, e1.MarginBounds.Height));
};
```

Comment: With this code, once the first page is printed, strings are cut off and a second page isn't printed. How can I account for a text box that may require two pages of printing? Additionally, the last word on the page even is half-printed, cut horizontally.

Comment: could you please add a sample data inside richtectbox to your post so i can test on my side

Comment: @Arcaster, plz add sample data inside richtextbox to your post so i can resolve all your problem